# Eloquent Relationships Laravel connecting multiple tables together

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am attempting to rewrite all my joins into Elequent model relationships.
Here is what i have so far:

```
class SectionAndUser
{
    public function sections()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Section');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
    ...
```

```
class User
{
    public function sectionAndUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SectionAndUser');
    }
    ...
```

```
class Section
{
    public function sectionAndUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SectionAndUser');
    }
    ...
```

With the select:

```
 $sections = User::find($userId)->sectionAndUser()->get();
```

I get the result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "section_id": 1,
    "user_id": 133
}
```

How do i now attach the 3 model section that carries all the data about section_id 1?

This is the join that i am hoping to achieve:

```
$id=Auth::id();
$results = DB::table('sections')
    ->join('section_and_users', function ($join) use ($id) {
        $join->on('sections.id', '=', 'section_and_users.section_id')
            ->where('section_and_users.user_id','=', $id);
    })
    ->get();
```

The expected result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "section_id": 1,
    "section_name": 'sectionName'
    "user_id": 133
}
```

Comment: Hi, any reason why you want to use 3 models instead of two?

Comment: Because its a many to many relationship, users can belong to many sections, section can have multiple users, so i made a link table

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way

```
$id=Auth::id();
$results = SectionAndUser::where('user_id', $id)->with('users', 'sections')->get();
```

then you could map it to get your desired output

```
$sections = collect($results)->map(function ($section){
     return [
          'id' => $section->id,
          'section_id' => $section->id,
          'section_name' => $section->sections->name,
          'user_id' => $section->user_id
     ];
```

});

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to create only models `Section` and `User`, and add the relationship as BelongsToMany.

```
class User
{
    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\Section');
    }
    ...
```

And

```
<?

class Section
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
    ...
```

And of course, you need to create the pivot table. You can consult [BelongsToMany documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.).

If you use this way, you can simple get the result with this query:

```
$section = Section::find(1); // This will return all your Section data
$section_related_users = $section->users; // This will return a collection of Users
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a many-to-many realtionship without the `SectionAndUser`-model.

With the `belongsToMany`-method, you can pass the name of the pivot table as a second argument. You can view `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships@belongsToMany` if you want to know what other arguments you can pass.

Section:

```
class Section extends Model
{
    ...
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'section_and_users');
    }
    ...
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...
    public function sections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Section::class, 'section_and_users');
    }
    ...
}
```

Then use it as this:
`$user->sections->where(...`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Post Model
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
// Role Model
 public function users()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\User');

    }

// User Model
 public function role()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
//Tag Model
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }

// Catgory Model
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
// controller 
 public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::latest()->get();
        return view('admin.post.index',compact('posts'));
    }
// posts tabel to user result get
 foreach($posts as $post){
$post->user->name
}
```